# How to write htaccess redirection from / to /admin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wanna write .htaccess condition if user visit webpage without anything behind domain, he must be redirected on domain/admin. So from / to /admin.  How can I do it simply?

Comment: Question: "How can I do it simply?" Answer: by implementing a redirection rule in your http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file. There are endless examples for that here on SO. I am sure you can find many you can use as a starting point for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /admin [L,R]
```

This will redirect your site homepage **/** to **/admin** .